# Can I use thanks to them in an enumeration?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is it okay to start a sentence with an enumeration with "thanks to"?

Here are some examples :

> **Thanks to** John, Mary and Suzy, we were able to have a lot of fun.
>
> The ministers of justice did a great job. **Thanks to them**, the police department and the fire department, everyone can sleep again.

If not, how could I write the second sentence in the second example?

Thanks a lot!
.G

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to have a [compound object](https://www.grammar-island.com/object-of-a-preposition.html) of the preposition "to".  Your sentence is grammatically correct.